# SELECT Max index for multiple column values in the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following database structure:

```
post_id | language | index
```

Data looks like:

```
1  |  en  |  1  
1  |  en  |  2  
1  |  en  |  3     

1  |  fr |  1  
1  |  fr |  2
```

`language` is a shortcode like `en`, `fr`, etc. `index` is an incrementing integer. There is at least one language code in the database.

I need to get the max value of `index` for each `language`.

Currently i get all languages for a post

```
SELECT DISTINCT(language) FROM my_table WHERE post_id = ?
```

and iterate then over the language array to get the Max value for each `language`

```
SELECT MAX(index) FROM my_table WHERE post_id = ? AND language = 'language_code'
```

Is there a way to execute just one query to achieve this result?

The result should look like:

```
1  |  en  |  3  
1  |  fr  |  2
```

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function. Also, I'm not convinced that your data set is properly representative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to achieve this.
You can check this link for more infos about the usage of `GROUP BY` with `MAX`: [SQL MAX() with group by](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/Max-with-group-by.php)

```
SELECT post_id, language, MAX(index) 
  FROM my_table 
  GROUP BY post_id, language;
```

The result of this query will be all the languages associated with the max index.

```
post_id | language | MAX(index)
1 | en |  3   
1 | fr |  2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There was already an answer with the same suggestion, but that wasn't working. If i try
`SELECT 
          language, 
          MAX(index)
     FROM my_table
          WHERE `post_id` = 1 
 GROUP BY language,
          index`

I receive a list with all indexes and their corresponding language. With the data of my post I receive all 5 rows not just two .

Comment: Yes sure you will receive the 5 rows since you are adding the index to the Group By. Remove it.

Comment: So try this : SELECT language, MAX(index) FROM my_table WHERE post_id = 1 GROUP BY language

Comment: Try adding WHERE to my answer and it will work. It is different than the previous suggestion. check the GROUP BY clause ;)

Answer (score 0):

**SQL GROUP BY** clause is used to group rows according to distinct values of column specified into **GROUP BY** clause

According to description as mentioned above as a solution to it please try executing following **SQL SELECT QUERY**

```
SELECT post_id,language, max(index)
FROM my_table group by language
```